# How password protect a Tp-Link access Point on my Mac

Tags: wireless-access-point

My apologies, but I'm not so tech savvy, but I've googled endlessly and cannot find any solutions.  so here goes!  We have internet via a satellite (roof top dish, which connects to a local mast, which is hardwired to some internet somewhere!) Inside the house we have a router, and I connected a powered box via an ethernet cable with 4 ports.  From these 4 ports I put further ethernet cables.  One goes to my printer, another one goes to a Tp-Link access point, which has three sockets.  I have connected my Mac and my tv to two of the sockets on this AP, the other is unused.  This AP, allows connection via wifi without a password.

My router is password protected and the wifi name is 'home', and requires a password to connect to it.  The access point shows a wifi name of TPLINK and requires no password.

I am looking for a way to password protect the AP (and maybe re-name it!)

I am thinking I'll probably need to plug my Mac directly in to my router maybe? and if so, what am I looking for?  My internet provider suggested I get an access point and 'hard-wire' it, as the wifi can't reach far around my house, but as I didn't buy the AP from them (they don't sell them!), they won't assist me.  I'm worried about people sitting outside the property and accessing my network, or worse!

Any help would be appreciated, and as dumbed down as you can manage.  Assume I know nothing, and you will be very close! thank you.

### --EDIT

I bought: TP-Link TL-SF1005P 5-Port 10/100Mbps Desktop Switch with 4-Port PoE & TP-Link Omada AC1200 Wireless MU-MMO Wall-Plate Access Point, as well as a plethora of cables including. cat6 UTP patch cable

I presume, I will need to plug my Mac directly into the router? I don't seem to be able to access the router remotely.

---

Thank you.
I bought:
TP-Link TL-SF1005P 5-Port 10/100Mbps Desktop Switch with 4-Port PoE &
TP-Link Omada AC1200 Wireless MU-MMO Wall-Plate Access Point,
as well as a plethora of cables including. cat6 UTP patch cable

I presume, I will need to plug my Mac directly into the router?  I don't seem to be able to access the router remotely.

Comment: You need to access the TP-Link settings and adjust the wireless settings accordingly. Make sure you're selecting the recommended settings - WPA2-AES only, not some WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP - including the password of your choosing.

Comment: 1)What is the point of the TPLink AP if you router already has WiFi (named 'home')? 2)Were you hoping to extend that existing WiFi network with the TPLink, not have two separate WiFi-names/SSID's? Thats a bit harder, but basically on TPLink set SSID to 'home' with same password & disable DHCP then it should work.  Devices are unlikely to seamlessly transition/move from from AP (main router one) to the other AP (TPLink), you'll lose WiFi briefly then it'll connect to the other AP

Answer (score 1):

As @ChanganAuto suggested you need to program the TPLINK AP (Access Point). The bottom of routers/AP's usually have a name or IP you put into a web browser to configure them. Providing the tp-link model can help us point you to the manual & relevant pages. Since your main router has a WiFi name (home), the AP is not technically needed, you could replace it with a [network switch](https://www.amazon.com/Computer-Networking-Switches/b/ref=dp_bc_aui_C_4?ie=UTF8&node=281414). However turning off the WiFi on the AP or password-protecting it's WiFi signal (TPLINK) is your cheapest option.

### --EDIT

1. Connect to `TP-Link` WiFi, WiFi name is printed on bottom of AP manual says
2. Open this website: `http://tplinkeap.net`
3. Login with username: `admin` and password: `admin`
4. It'll have you create an account, another username & password
5. Then you can uncheck the 2.4GHz & 5GHz Wireless Radio to turn off the TP-Link WiFi

However on closer inspection this [AP (EAP225-Outdoor?)](https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/omada-sdn-access-point/eap225-outdoor/) has only one port & you said you have more ports than that!? AC1200 seems to be a series or refer to multiple TP-Link routers/AP's so you need further model details for best guidance.

Comment: Thank you. I bought: TP-Link TL-SF1005P 5-Port 10/100Mbps Desktop Switch with 4-Port PoE & TP-Link Omada AC1200 Wireless MU-MMO Wall-Plate Access Point, as well as a plethora of cables including. cat6 UTP patch cable

I presume, I will need to plug my Mac directly into the router? I don't seem to be able to access the router remotely.